# is their any way that update primary Key( auto increment) order by foreign key or any other ids?

Tags: mysql

I am using the MySql database and now my table name `abc` have the order_ids field and in another table `def` i have primary field ds_id
my `def` table's primary key have Now for example, something like this in the ID column: `12, 13, 14, 19, 20...` I deleted the `15, 16, 18` and `19` rows.
and order_ids for example, `2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 2, 12..` etc.
is it possible i rearrange the my `def` table primary key order by order_ids?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You never touch primary key, you don't update it, you just use it for deleting or for looking data up. I can't decipher what you're actually asking for, can you please make it easier to understand? Also, do you know what `ORDER BY` clause is used for? You shouldn't manually update stuff in order to get something ordered when pulling data out.

Comment: i know its hard to touch the primary key. but what i need , there are some mishmash in my database, for resolving that issue i am looking for rearranging the data by my order_ids. other wise i have to do it by manually.